# How do I merge multiple different blocks of data in Tiny But Strong?

Tags: php, excel, xlsx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to merge multiple blocks of different data in a TinyButStrong Excel document (each block of data is for a different worksheet).

When I try separate MergeBlock statements as follows:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('b1', $block_b1); $TBS->MergeBlock('b2', $block_b2);
```

...the results ignore all but the first block.

I see in the [TBS examples](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=blocks&m=result), a case where merging of multiple blocks using the same data is done.

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('blk1,blk2,blk3,blk4,blk5,blk6,blk7',$country); // Merge several blocks with the same data
```

...but nothing in the TBS documentation or examples about how to merge different arrays in each block.

How do I merge multiple blocks of different data in Tiny But Strong Excel (or even just in Tiny But Strong).

Answer (score 1):

In an XLSX file, each worksheet is stored in a different sub-file.
So you have to use the  command [OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#opentbs_select_sheet) in order to select the sheet before to merge something in it.

```
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET, 2);
$TBS->MergeBlock('blk2', $country);
```

On the first worksheet the block is correctly merged because sub-file corresponding to the first worksheet is loaded by default by OpenTBS.

In an ODS file (LibreOffice), all worksheets are stored in the same sub-file. Then command `OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET` has simply no effect (and no error). But all blocks has to hold a different name.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you again.  Is there a better place to go to learn about Tiny But Strong and their Excel plug in besides the TBS site?  I don't even see OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET on [the Excel plug in site](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/excel/tbs_plugin_excel.htm).

Comment: I suggest [demo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo) and [doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc)